# How do I connect to SQLite database with adminer 4.3.1?

Tags: sqlite, adminer

HI we are using Adminer 4.3.1.

We choose system sqlite3 + localhost + location to DB file.

The error is not clear. I understood SQlite is supported. And I am directed to hardcoding functions to login. Don't I just need to use the form?

In short: how does one connect to a SQlite3 file using Admin?

Helpt appreciated ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, it does look like SQLite is broken in 4.3.1 because it is fixed in 4.3.2-dev, interestingly the login form has fewer options when SQLite is selected.

[image]

You can get the latest version by cloning the github repo and running adminer/sqlite.php

Comment: Still an issue with 4.7.7

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a plugin, which returns an instance of `AdminerLoginPasswordLess` and put it in the directory `plugins-enabled`.

Content for ./plugins-enabled/login-password-less.php:

```
<?php
require_once('plugins/login-password-less.php');

return new AdminerLoginPasswordLess(password_hash("my_password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
```

Tested with Adminer v4.8.1.

If you want a ready-to-use Docker container which solves this problem, see [this link](https://github.com/fluidblue/adminer-sqlite).